# PineScript: How to append string in a custom screener indicator

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am developing a PineScript screener where based on certain conditions I want to build up a string which I want to set on alert.

My whole code is in TradingView link [My Screener](https://in.tradingview.com/script/17QnvRsR-5EMA-BollingerBand-Nifty-Stock-Scanner/). It's publicly available.

My code snippet is something like this (relevant section of alert):

```
    if matrix.rows(screenerMtx) > 0
        var string alertLabel = '5EMA_BB_Alert'
        for i = 0 to matrix.rows(screenerMtx) - 1
                // This is where the code to generate a table to show in the chart.
                alertLabel := alertLabel + '\n' + id_symbol(matrix.get(screenerMtx, i, 0)) + ' [' + cond_text + ']'
        
        if (doAlert) // doAlert is a settings
            alert(alertLabel, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
            alertLabel := na
```

My expectation is that: In the alert message I would like to see the symbols matching the alert such that looking at the notification one can know which chart to open to take the trade.

But I am getting only one of the symbol as in the alert, not all symbols.

What am I missing here?